# Change navigation button for different type of users

Tags: php, html

I want to add extra navigation button for admin and customer differently.If admin is logged in an extra naviagtion button should be added and same for customer. I don't get any errors but the if else block (user_type) doesn't execute and I don't get any extra navigation button. What is wrong in my code.

index.php

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <div class="menu">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
              <li role="presentation"><a href="index.php" class="active"  >Home</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="subscribe.php" >Subscribe</a></li>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="signup.php">Sign up</a></li>
              <?php

              if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))  //check if user is logged in
              {

                if(!empty($_POST['user_type']))
                   {
                       $user_type=$_POST['user_type'];
                       if($user_type==1)                //type 1 is admin
                       {
                echo'<li role="presentation"><a href="customers.php">Customers</a></li>';
                echo'<li role="presentation"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';
                       }
                      elseif($user_type==2) {             //type 2 is customer
                echo'<li role="presentation"><a href="account.php">My account</a></li>';
                echo'<li role="presentation"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';
                      }
                  }              
              }

              else{
                    echo'<li role="presentation"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>';
                }   
              ?>
              <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

signup.php

```
    <form action="psignup.php"  method="POST" class="register-form" id="register-form">
    <select required type="text" name="user_type" class="dropdown">
                                        <option value="NULL">Select User Type</option>
                                        <option value=1>Admin</option>
                                        <option value=2>Customer</option>
                                    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: where user_type come from ? Can it be `$_SESSION['user_type']` ? this question needs more details.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($user_type);` and check what it actually contains. But do you really get it from the posted data and not, as the previous comment suggests from the session?

Comment: $_POST['user_type'] check value if this and it should comes from session not by post data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that after log in, you validate user's credentials and you create the `$_SESSION['login_user']`.

Use the same logic to validate the user and according to his'/her's user type, create the `$_SESSION['user_type']` right after your `$_SESSION['login_user']` setup, within a conditional statement.

That way, you can check for the `if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 1)` in every page of your site.

Remember to clear or destroy your `$_SESSION` variables during logout and filtering your posted values before assigning them into your session (i.e. `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['user_type'], ENT_QUOTES))` see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['user_type']` will only exist once, after the first time the user completes your signup form. That's just how POST variables work - they are populated with data the user has submitted in the current request; they don't persist during subsequent requests.

So if you want to display the menu for every page after the user logs in, then you can't use it. You would need to store the user type value in the Session, and fetch it from there (just like you are doing with the `login_user` value already.)